# How to put a newline in the message of a new Error object Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, error-handling, newline

I have a function in a service something like this:

`Policies` is a list of functions that will **throw an error** if a policy is   violatted (e.g.  password does not have numbers or capital letters)

```
 function myFunction(policies, password){ 
  var policiesError = ''; 
  policies.forEach(function(policy) {      
    try {
      policy(password, payload);
    } catch (err) {
      policiesError += err.message + '\n';   // Also tried `concat()`
    }
  });
  if (policiesError){
    throw new Error(policiesError);
  }
}
```

And in a my `controller` I have:

```
try{
  myService.myFunction(myFunctions, 'password');
} catch (err){
  $scope.policiesError = err.message; // Which is used in as {{policiesError}} to display   
}
```

The result of the message in the controller is something like:

```
"Password too shortPassword has no lettersInvalid characters in password"
```

but I actually need it to be:

```
"Password too short
Password has no letters
Invalid characters in password"
```

It's quite simple, but I've banged my head against the table for a while and it's quite frustrating.

Any suggestions on how to achieve a nice formatted message  using `new Error` and catching it?

Comment: Is it HTML? Then use `<br />`.

Comment: Will every new line be seperated by a period? If so, you can simply use: `err.message.split('.')` followed by `err.message.join('\n')`

Comment: I might have missed that I also validate special characters, that's I can't split by Period. (also some error messages have periods in them)

Comment: "*not actually alert*" - what then? Please show the actual code that displays the message, because it seems to be the culprit when newlines don't show up properly

Comment: @Bergi, 
`$scope.var_in_scope = err.message;`  and that, is being used in html like:
`<span ng-if="var_in_scope" >{{var_in_scope}}</span>`

Comment: It is weird that you don't even see any whitespaces where the linebreaks are, but you should try giving that span a [`white-space: pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) style.

Comment: @Bergi, 
yeah, my guess is that `new Error(message)` trims all the newlines.
Maybe it's because we don't expect long explanations with `Error` but just a sentence.
Ok, I'll give `pre-wrap` a try. Thank you, btw.

Comment: Well, you can check yourself by doing `console.log(err.message.match(/\n/g).length)`. What does it log? And what browser are you using?

Comment: @Bergi 
I did `console.log(err.message.match(/\n/g).length)`
It did count the corresponding ammount of lines. So they don't get trimmed.
That made me think of a CSS property  ...
So I went back to CSS to find out that I hadn't seen white-space property from a parent.  So yeah... the error was at CSS ...
on my defense my changes for this bugfix I'm working on only had effect on JS, so I had no clue haha.
Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, @Bergi made me realize that the issue was at a CSS property regarding `white-space-`
I was writing a new feature in our code, so I didn't move any of CSS and didn't think of it.
But yeah, CSS was getting rid of the `\n` added in Javascript.

apologies for not checking something THAT simple from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\r\n` not just `\n`.

```js
throw new Error("\r\nLine 1 Error Description.\r\nLine 2 Error Description.");
```

Will return:

```js
JavaScript Error line(102): // Your error with message below.
Line 1 Error Description.
Line 2 Error Description.
```